# Override Less Mixins

Tags: css, npm, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I am fully aware **mixins (classes) in Less couldn't be overridden**, but maybe some npm packages exist that could do it or smth else? Currently compiling with grunt-contrib-less

```
/// vendor_mixins.less
.do-my-css(@color:red) {color: @color; display: table}

// custom_mixins.less
.do-my-css(@color:red) {color: @color;}

// public.less
body {
.do-my-css()
};

// real output
body {color: red; display: table;}

// expecting
body {color: red}
```

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite it? can't you write a new mixin? 

Comment: It's simple. Just because I don't want to intervene in the vendor code keeping the ability to upgrade from the source and call for support.